# Meaning of 才 in 这样 才 更 容易 获得 幸福

Tags: adverbs

Below sentence is quoted from the official textbook of hsk4.

> 有的时候，没有 机会 可以 主动 制造 机会，这样 才 更 容易 获得 幸福。

I think that 才 here can be interpreted in 2 ways.

1. just(adverb)
2. ability

Which is correct here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

才 has many meanings in different contexts, in here, it is :[A: condition] + [才 (only then)] + [B: subsequent statement]--> "才" indicates: "must meet a condition first, then the subsequent statement can stand"

[这样] [更容易] [获得幸福]。

[This way] [easier to] [obtain happiness]

This way is easier to obtain happiness

~

[这样] [**才**] [更容易] [获得] [幸福]。

[This way] [**only then**] [easier to] [obtain happiness]

**Only** this way **then**, be easier to obtain happiness

Another example:

二十一歲算成年 = 21 years old is considered an adult

二十一歲[才]算成年 = [only] 21 years [then], be considered an adult (you have to be 21, then be considered an adult)